# How to convert system.string to the type system.DateTime using powershell

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMCxG.png)I need to remove those users that come into an special OU and check is the have been more than 6 monthes in this OU remove them. I dont know if i have right but I use Whenchanged attribute and also checked with Get-ADgroupmemberDate but my script works well untill i have one user in OU or group, once I have more than 2 users I get this error

> Cannot convert 'System.String[]' to the type 'System.DateTime'

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud' -Properties whenChanged | ForEach {
     $userinfo = Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase 'OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud' -properties whenChanged | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select-Object DisplayName, whenChanged 
     $today = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
     $userData = $userinfo.Whenchanged
     $convert = ([string]$userData.ToshortDatestring()).Split()


     $result = (New-TimeSpan -Start $convert -End $today).Days 


        If ($result -ge 10) {
            #Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud" | Disable-ADAccount
            #Get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase "OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud" | where-object { $_.Enabled -eq $false } | remove-ADobject -Confirm:$false
            "Hello"
            }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really over doing this with the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet.

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to get a list of all user objects in that OU that have not been modified for over 6 months (although your code suggests *10 days*..).
Then, if that user object is Enabled, you want to disable it and if the user object already was disabled you need to remove it.

In that case this should do it:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)    # test for users that have been in this OU for more than 6 months
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud' -Properties DisplayName, Modified | ForEach-Object {
    # iterating over this user collection means that in each run, the $_ automatic variable contains a single user
    if ($_.Modified -lt $refDate) {
        if ($_.Enabled) {
            Write-Host "Disabling user $($_.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $_ | Disable-ADAccount
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Deleting user $($_.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Magenta
            $_ | Remove-ADUser
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey). 
If you need to compare the date to *midnight* of X months ago (basically leave out the time part of the date), change the declaration of `$refDate` to

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddMonths(-6)
```

and change the test to

```
if ($_.Modified.Date -lt $refDate) {
```

---

As per your comment to write out a CSV for all users that are disabeled/deleted by the above function, you could implement that using:

```
$today   = Get-Date
$refDate = $today.Date.AddMonths(-6)    # test for users that have been in this OU for more than 6 months
$result  = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=testOU,DC=fire,DC=cloud' -Properties DisplayName, Modified | ForEach-Object {
    # iterating over this user collection means that in each run, the $_ automatic variable contains a single user
    if ($_.Modified.Date -lt $refDate) {
        # create an object with some details about the user for export to CSV
        $out = [PsCustomObject]@{
            'UserName'    = $_.DisplayName
            'AccountName' = $_.SamAccountName
            'Date'        = $today
            'Action'      = ''
        }
        if ($_.Enabled) {
            Write-Host "Disabling user $($_.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $out.Action = 'Disabled'
            $_ | Disable-ADAccount
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Deleting user $($_.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Magenta
            $out.Action = 'Deleted'
            $_ | Remove-ADUser
        }
        # emit the PsCustomObject so it gets collected in variable $result
        $out
    }
}

if ($result) {
    # output the $result collection to screen
    $result

    # output to a CSV file
    $result | Export-Csv -Path 'Ex-users.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
else { "No users were deleted or disabled" }
```

Comment: would it be worthwhile in this case to use `(Get-Date).Date.AddMonths(-$MonthsAgo)` so that the comparisons are against the whole day [midnite] instead of whatever time of day you run the script?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for this. I have included your tip in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the respond.......10 days is an example.I had plan to compair it with 180 days which means 6 monthes....but this script that you write seems helpfull I'll test it soon and update you about the result

Comment: @Theo - you are welcome! i have been bitten by having the timestamp in there where it offset the date math _just enuf_ to make things off by one day. i thot it was a standard "off by one" error ... and spent _hours_ hunting for it. [*blush*]

Comment: how can I export all users that got removed to a .CSV ?  Write-Host "Deleting user $($_.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Magenta
            $_ | Remove-ADUser -Confirm:$false
              "$($_.DisplayName)" > C:\testps1\deleteduser.csv

            I've added this last line but it export only one displayname but i need to export all users  and the date who got removed in .CSV file

Comment: @Davoud.Ro I have added extended code for outputting a CSV file. Hope you like it!